# array.forEach.call vs array.map.call

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, foreach, selector

To loop over the results of `querySelectorAll` in JavaScript, is one of the following more preferable than the other?

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div'){
  // do something
})

[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('div'){
  // do something
})
```

Essentially, I'm wondering if these each achieve the same result of providing access to each dom element returned from `querySelectorAll`. If so, what are reasons one might want to use one over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**forEach** operates on the original array elements. (*If you want just iterate over all element you should use forEach*)

**map** is running through your array, applying a function to each element, and emitting the result as a new array. (*if you want to apply some changes to each element you should use map*)

Comment: When you say "apply some changes" as a reason for using map, would this include simple dom manipulation such as adding or removing classes? I've tried adding and removing classes using both options (`forEach` and `map`) and each works...

Comment: I think if you need just change attribute (class, id etc.) and don't need new list - better use forEach - my thoughts on this subject http://jsbin.com/hehame/1/edit?js. What is your opinion? maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference in which elements will be looped over between `map` and `forEach`. If the element in the array is `undefined`, it will not be invoked in `map`, but it will be invoked on `forEach`.

Obviously this distinction does not apply in the case of `querySelectorAll`, which will never return `undefined` in its results.

So the only difference between them is that of what the function returns. `forEach` has no return value. `map` executes a function on each member of the array and returns the results. So, for instance, you could do this:

```
var values = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'), function(el) {
    return el.value;
});
```

This will return an array containing the `value` of every element selected by `querySelectorAll('input')`.

So you should use `map` when that's what you want; otherwise, use `forEach`.

NB that `Array.prototype.every` and `Array.prototype.some` also exist; there may be times when they would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

forEach - only iterates the array elements.

map - iterates the array elements and returns a new array. for example..

```
var temp = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('div'), function(e){
  return e.id;
  // do something
})
```

temp is new array having id of all div elements;